# File dumping from Binary issue

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I'm trying to code a dump tool and There is a file in memory at a pacific address that holds a file with 41mb's in file size.
I'm trying to write that file with the file size to the directory.
Any advice or opinions you can provide much appreciation.

I've tried this...

Here is my updated code:

```
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 int sizevalue = 43.417254; // size of file
 DWORD address = 0x43417254;
 char Wfilename[14] = "cartfile.dat";
 char Rfilename[14] = "cartfile.dat";

 //entry
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
 HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "gametutorial");

 if (hwnd == NULL)
 {
 cout << "Cannot find window." << endl;
 Sleep(3000);
 exit(-1);
 }
 else
 {
 DWORD procID;
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
 HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, PROCESS_VM_WRITE, procID);
 if (procID == NULL)
 {
 cout << "Cannot obtain process." << endl;
 Sleep(3000);
 exit(-1);
 }
 else
 {

 for (;;)
 {
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F10))
 {
 printf("Dumping cartfile now... \n");
 ofstream outputStream("cartfile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
 if (outputStream.is_open())
 {
 std::cout << "file opened okay\n";
 }
 else
 {
 std::cout << "Error opening file\n";
 }
    ReadProcessMemory_(handle, (void*)address, &sizevalue, Rfilename, 
    sizeof(sizevalue), 0);
    WriteProcessMemory_(handle, (void*)address, &sizevalue, Wfilename, 
 sizeof(sizevalue), 0); 
 0);
 outputStream.close();
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
 Sleep(1);
 }
 }
 }
 }

 BOOL WriteProcessMemory_(HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpBaseAddress, LPCVOID 
 lpBuffer, CHAR* lpfile, SIZE_T nSize, SIZE_T* lpNumberOfBytesWritten)
 {
 return 0;
 }

 BOOL ReadProcessMemory_(HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpBaseAddress, LPCVOID 
 lpBuffer, CHAR* lpfile, SIZE_T nSize, SIZE_T* lpNumberOfBytesRead)
 {
 return 0;
 }
```

Here is my header file...

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include .lib header

BOOL WriteProcessMemory_(
HANDLE  hProcess,
LPVOID  lpBaseAddress,
LPCVOID lpBuffer,
CHAR* lpfile,
SIZE_T  nSize,
SIZE_T* lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);

BOOL ReadProcessMemory_(
HANDLE  hProcess,
LPVOID  lpBaseAddress,
LPCVOID lpBuffer,
CHAR* lpfile,
SIZE_T  nSize,
SIZE_T* lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

But it still dumps the cartfile with 0 file size 0kb.
So what now?

But it only dumps the Cartfile but it is 0 size.
Which the bytes in the place in the binary holds a file with 41 mb's in file size.
The file opens fine so I can open the file successfully.
It must be something to do with the way it is writing the file and size of the file from the bytes in memory?
So what Am I doing wrong?

[Here is a pic of the results on how these bytes are 41mb's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8my67.png)

Comment: How are you so sure there is something at address `0x81865e58` that needs to be dumped? Where and how did you derive such an address?

Comment: Since morden OS use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), any memory address from other processes is meaningless.

Comment: What is `ofs` for? Are you trying to write 2072 bytes from the other file you didn't read anything from?

Comment: I edited my code. I took the bytes and converted it to decimal which equals to 41 mbs when converted to MB. So that gave me the correct size of the bytes in memory. I used a hex editor to get those bytes that I derived from. @Andy

Comment: Checking the stream-state of `outputStream` immediately after opening and again after the write may provide some clues to any stream error that is occurring.

Comment: The opening of the file opens okay so it must be something to do with the write. @David C. Rankin

Comment: you have to use `ReadProcessMemory` if you want to read a process' memory in Windows

Comment: I'm just trying to write a file that is stored at those bytes in memory. That's it there is no need to read the process memory unless it is mandatory to do so before the writing of the file stored at those bytes in memory. @Andy

Comment: then use `WriteProcessMemory`.

Comment: Yeah but I'm not writing to a set of bytes in memory I'm writing from those bytes in memory with a value of 41mb's and dumping a filename as "cartfile.dat". So I don't see why that would help when I'm not writing to the bytes? @Andy

Comment: I updated my code above. So what Am I doing wrong any suggestions?

Comment: What do you think this does? `int sizevalue = 43.417254;` `WriteProcessMemory_` and `ReadProcessMemory_` don't do anything and you never write to your output file.

Comment: Then If I am doing it wrong help me out man give me a code example of how you would do it just help me out man. I appreciate everything you have done.

Comment: You could easily google this "C++ how to read process memory"

Comment: I know what the function does But if you noticed I created a new readprocessmemory_ function to add the CHAR* lpfile which is the parameter to call the Rfilename Wfilename. My code compiles okay it writes the cartfile to my folder but it still is 0kb in file size maybe I am going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that writes 64k of memory from a running Notepad++ process. Perhaps you can adapt it to your needs.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

void* GetBaseAddress(HANDLE processHandle)
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return hMods[0];
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "new 1 - Notepad++");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot find window.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD procID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, procID);
    if (procID == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot obtain process.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F10))
        {
            // I don't have a fixed address so I just find the address of the first loaded module in the process.
            // You need to determine your address and replace this.
            void *address = GetBaseAddress(handle);

            // Resize this buffer to whatever the size is you need.
            std::vector<char> buffer(64 * 1024);

            SIZE_T bytesRead = 0;
            BOOL ret = ReadProcessMemory(handle, address, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &bytesRead);
            if (!ret)
            {
                std::cout << "Error (" << GetLastError() << ") reading memory\n";
                return -1;
            }
            if (bytesRead != buffer.size())
            {
                std::cout << "Memory size mismatch. Requested " << buffer.size() << ", Received " << bytesRead << "\n";
                return -1;
            }

            std::ofstream out("memory.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            if (!out)
            {
                std::cout << "Error opening file\n";
                return -1;
            }
            out.write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you so much for helping me out with an example I'm very grateful for you taking the time thank you. I learn more from reading code and adapting more than reading text I'm just that type of programmer.